# How do you call a variable created earlier in a when in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to list the first 100 of a shuffled list. I'm telling it to shuffle if the list is at 0 and then increment. I then am trying to call that list in another section of the when but it's not working. How can I accomplish this?

```kotlin
    when (countF) {
                    0 -> {
                        //shuffle at 0
                        val randomChaos = chaosList.asSequence().shuffled().take(chaosList.count()).toList()
                        cResult.text = randomChaos.elementAt(countF) + countF + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + this.cResult.text
                        countF++
                    }
                    1-99 -> {
                        //show 1-99
                        cResult.text = randomChaos.elementAt(countF) + countF + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + this.cResult.text
                        countF++
                    }
                    100 -> countF = 0
```

Comment: The branches of the `when` are mutually exclusive. If the second branch is executed, the first one is not. So the variable you're trying to refer to not only doesn't exist but also is not initialized at all. Are you trying to call this code in a loop and reuse the variable initialization from a previous iteration? It would help to see more code surrounding this `when`

Comment: The most likely fix for this would be to declare the variable holding the shuffled list outside of the piece of code that repeatedly calls this `when`. If it's in a loop, declare the list outside of the loop. If it's called via some callbacks reacting to user input, maybe you should declare the list as a property in the containing class, or in a viewmodel or whatever place holds the data here

Comment: Side note: `asSequence()` is pointless here because `shuffled()` on sequences will need to collect all elements into a list anyway, and you only add one extra operation after that. Also `take(chaosList.count())` takes the whole list, so why call it at all? I guess the whole line is equivalent to just `chaosList.shuffled()`

Comment: fun roll() { var randomChaos = chaosList.asSequence().shuffled().take(chaosList.count()).toList() }

Can I just use this function to generate this shuffled list and then call it in the when? If I try this in my program it says randomChaos isn't a variable in the when statements...

Comment: You could indeed use a function, but you would need to return the list that it computes. I think you misunderstand the scopes of local variables. If you declare a variable in a block of code, it only exists in this block but it cannot be used elsewhere. Also, each time your function is called, it would return a new list randomized differently. If you need to store some state to reuse it, you probably need properties instead. That said, there might be shorter and less stateful alternatives but it's hard to help without a bit more context about how you use this piece of code

Comment: my ultimate goal is to randomize an array and then display elementAt(CountF) which starts at 0 and increments each time the button is pressed. I want to reset countF to 0 once it hits 50 or 100 or so and also if/when the clear button is pressed.

Comment: so i can randomize the list and it stays in that shuffled state the entire time but i dont know how to re-shuffle it when i reset or hit the limit of what i want to show

Comment: so I tried this which is as simple as i thought i could make it (the countF within the + is for debugging where I am on countF)
And it doesnt work because randomChaos isn't declared

    if (countF < 1) { val randomChaos = chaosList.shuffled() }
    cResult.text = randomChaos.elementAt(countF) + countF + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + this.cResult.text
    countF++
    if (countF > 50) { countF = 0 }

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create the `val randomChaos` *before* the `when` enclosure for it to be available in the scope of multiple branches of the `when` statement.

That said, the way you're getting a random element is very convoluted. `take(chaosList.count())` is completely redundant. And since you don't use multiple sequence operators, creating a sequence is also redundant. Finally, you are only pulling a single item from the random list, so it's unnecessary to create a shuffled list in the first place. Using `elementAt()` on a shuffled list is no different than picking any element out of that shuffled list, or simply picking a random item out of a list that isn't shuffled at all.

Also, the first two branches of your `when` statement currently would produce exactly the same results so they can be merged.

Based on what you described, I'm guessing you had this when statement inside a loop that tries to run it 100 times so you can list all the items. For that to work, you would need to shuffle the list one time outside the loop, and then you could iterate its elements in the loop.

However, there are functions that can make it easier to do what you're suggesting. Here's an example:

```
val randomChaos = chaosList.shuffled()
cResult.text = randomChaos.asSequence()
    .take(100)
    .withIndex()
    .joinToString("\n") { (i, value) ->
        "$value-$i"
    }
```

In this case, using a Sequence helps avoid creating an intermediate list to hold the first 100 values.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var randomChaos  = chaosList.shuffled()
    fun cShuf() { randomChaos = chaosList.shuffled() }

    cRoll.setOnClickListener() {
        cResult.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
        if (countF < 1) { cShuf() }
        cResult.text = randomChaos.elementAt(countF) + "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" + this.cResult.text
        countF++
        if (countF > 100) countF = 0
    }
```

I have figured out how to use a function to generate a new shuffe of the list once I've hit > 100 shown.
My issue with making it a function was I was trying to use val variable in the function but the variable already existed so I didn't need to use val, just the name of the variable.